# How to redirect to a edit node page with RedirectResponse?

Tags: 8, redirection

From a hook (not form_alter), I want redirect the user to a node edit page (like mywebsite/node/[nid]/edit)
How can I do that with the `RedirectResponse` class?

After searches, I found the following code.

```
new RedirectResponse(\Drupal::url('route.name'));
```

How can I get/find the route.name for a node edit page?

**Update :**

According the cilefen's answer =) 
From my entity_insert hook :

```
function article_entity_insert(EntityInterface $entity) {
  if ($entity->bundle() == "article"){
    Url::fromRoute('entity.node.edit_form',['node', $entity->id()]); //But when I create a new node, the "view" page is loaded and not the edit page
    dpm($entity->id()); //show the node id
  }
}
```

**Update 2 :**

The command

```
dpm(Url::fromRoute('entity.node.edit_form',['node', $entity->id()]));
```

return

```
Drupal\Core\Url Object
(
    [urlGenerator:protected] => 
    [urlAssembler:protected] => 
    [accessManager:protected] => 
    [routeName:protected] => entity.node.edit_form
    [routeParameters:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => node
            [1] => 31
        )

    [options:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [external:protected] => 
    [unrouted:protected] => 
    [uri:protected] => 
    [internalPath:protected] => 
    [_serviceIds:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

But the command

```
dpm(Url::fromRoute('entity.node.edit_form',['node', $entity->id()])->toString());
```

Return this error :

> [Mon Feb 15 01:38:30.081002 2016] [:error] [pid 10219] [client
>   192.168.1.48:49246] Uncaught PHP Exception Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: "Some mandatory
>   parameters are missing ("node") to generate a URL for route
>   "entity.node.edit_form"." at
>   /var/www/system/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php
>   line 757, referer: http://192.168.1.44/system/node/add/article

Comment: What is the value of Url::fromRoute('entity.node.edit_form',['node', $entity->id()])->toString();

Comment: Thank you for your help :) I update my main post (update 2), I get a strange error when I use toString(), I don't understand why...

Comment: Sorry, it should be: Url::fromRoute('entity.node.edit_form',['node' => $entity->id()])->toString();

Comment: The value returned is : /system/node/50/edit. But the view page is always loaded by default

Answer (score 9):

Note that `\Drupal::url()` is deprecated. You should use the static methods of the `Url` class to create URLs from routes.

To find the route names, use the Drupal console `drupal router:debug`. From that I found:

```
 entity.node.edit_form  /node/{node}/edit
```

I think what you need is `Url::fromRoute('entity.node.edit_form', ['node' => 1])` where 1 is the node ID to be edited.

Comment: "To find the route names, use the Drupal console drupal router:debug" , Ho ! thank you for this tips :)

Comment: If you have the node object that you want to redirect to, you can also do this: $node->toUrl('edit-form')->toString()

Comment: Hmmm I used "Url::fromRoute" from an entity_insert hook, but when I create a new node, Im not redirect to the edit page but the view page :/ I update my main post with my code

Answer (score 4):

From your controller class, you can use the [redirect()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Routing%21UrlGeneratorTrait.php/function/UrlGeneratorTrait%3A%3Aredirect/8.2.x) method like so :

```
return $this->redirect('entity.node.edit_form', ['node' => $node_id]);
```

For other ways of doing this, see [drupal_goto() has been removed](https://www.drupal.org/node/2023537).

There's no need to fiddle with Urls or string conversion as discussed in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
Url::fromRoute('entity.node.edit_form', ['node', $entity->id()])->toString()
                                               ^^
```

I think you want:

```
Url::fromRoute('entity.node.edit_form', ['node' => $entity->id()])->toString();
                                               ^^^^
```

The first has an *indexed* array as the second parameter to Url::fromRoute(), the second has a *named* array as the second parameter.