# How to redirect page to specific url?

Tags: 8

How to redirect page to specific url **suppose blog-landing** page to **blog-landing/all** page

How to target specific page **/blog-landing** page when user enters url into browser user should redirect to **blog-landing/all**

What i have tried :

```
 function bootstrap_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

 $request = \Drupal::request();
 $current_path = $request->getPathInfo();
 $path_args = explode('/', $current_path);
 $first_argument = $path_args[1];
  if($first_argument =="blog-landing")
  {
    $response = new Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse('/node/12/edit');
 $response->send(); 
return;

}

else
{

 echo "sorry not redirected";
 }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a default parameter (for example `blog_id`) in your `routing.yml` file:

```
mymodule.route_name:
  path: '/blog-landing/{blog_id}'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Show blogs.'
    _controller: '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\BlogController::viewAction'
    blog_id: 'all'
```

If the `blog_id` parameter is omitted the default value ('all') is used.

**After your edit:**

If you are redirecting via the `RedirectResponse()` class you should call the `send()` method in order to redirect.

Comment: Tx  i have done changes in my code after your suggestion

Comment: can you suggest on more changes in my code why its not creating complete path  /node/12/edit

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question. The /node/{node}/edit route is a core route: `entity.node.edit_form` => `/node/{node}/edit`. For redirecting to a node edit page please see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/190376/how-to-redirect-to-a-edit-node-page-with-redirectresponse

Answer (score 0):

One other way, without using additional modules or rewrite rules would be to create a content with the alias **oldurl** adding the following full html content to the body:

```
<script>
window.location="http://www.yoursite.com/newurl"
</script>
```

Comment: Like I said, create a content (of any content type, ex: page), on the body field, select the format full html, put the above JavaScript code. Create an alias of with the url you want to be redirect so that the path to that content becomes something http://www.yoursite.com/oldurl, and save the content.